# attach multiple unwrapped objects for wings for video game to rig

Tags: animation, uv, game-engine, bones

I am trying to make wings for a video game, what may be the best workflow to join the feathers to the wing structure and not the main body as they will be separate in-game? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: maybe use parent and child relation?

Comment: Would that be with the rigged bones themselves?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure, I just had an idea that it may be working the same way as people are making movable armor for their game character, it is attached to the main body but still moves with it separately. Try to look out for it, I once did character that had shoulder plates as objects parented to shoulder bones

Comment: Interesting! Thank you very much!